# Compare date inside map and get the list value

Tags: flutter, dart

How to get the date and list data in

`Map<DateTime, List> _events;`

Sample data

`_events = {`
`_selectedDay: ['Event A7', 'Event B7', 'Event C7', 'Event D7'],`
`_selectedDay.add(Duration(days: 1)): ['Event A8', 'Event B8', 'Event C8', 'Event D8']}`

I want to check if the date in _events if it is equal to date now and get the list

```
for(var i = 0; i< _events.length; i++) {
      var list = _events[i].toString();
      print(list);
    }
```

Comment: Please modify the sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Map<DateTime, List> _events;
DateTime _selectedDay = new DateTime(2020, 10, 14);
_events = { _selectedDay: ['Event A7', 'Event B7', 'Event C7', 'Event D7'], _selectedDay.add(Duration(days: 1)): ['Event A8', 'Event B8', 'Event C8', 'Event D8']};
for (var key in _events.keys) {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    if(key.compareTo(DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day)) == 0){
        print(_events[key]);
    }
}
```

This will check is date in map DateTime.now.
For checking is used compareTo function you have documentation here: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.2/dart-core/DateTime/compareTo.html

And to get all events from current date you use _events[key] in for function.